# Scala, ZIO - retry if data is not inserted into cassandra database

Tags: scala, cassandra, nosql, scala-cats, zio

I have a simple method which add data into Cassandra database:

```
 def addData(data: SomeData): Task[Either[Exception, Unit]]
```

I use it to add same data to two tables at the same type:

```
for {
 persistOneTable <- repo.addData(data).mapError(SomeError(_))
 persistSecondTable <- repo2.addData(data).mapError(SomeError(_))
} yield ()
```

My question is, how should I change this code to retry inserting to table if it failed at first time? I do not want to have inconsistent data in tables, so if it failed after insert to first table I want to retry it and then insert to second table and also retry there until it is added to have exactly same data in both tables

Comment: Do you want to retry only when the `Task` fails? Or does the `Exception` in the `Either` also indicate that a retry should happen?

Comment: Only if `Task` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `retry` on effects and handover a retry policy.

For example `addData(data).retry(policy = Schedule.recurs(5))`.
You can combine schedulers with the `&&` (and) or `||` (or) operators.

There are also specialised retry methods on effects like `retryN(n: Int)`.
Maybe one of them fits your needs.